# How can I do to extract the good date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am using javascript and I'm facing with that problem :

```
let myDate = new Date(2023,4,25)

=> Date Thu May 25 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)

myDate.toISOString()

=> "2023-05-24T22:00:00.000Z"
```

Whereas I want "2023-05-25T00:00:00.000Z" I mean 25 instead of 24

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !